# SwiftUI: Optimal way to disable NavigationLink which has a custom ButtonStyle

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a navigation link which has a custom ButtonStyle:

```
NavigationLink(destination: NextScreen()) {
   Text("Next")
}
.buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle(disabled: !isValidPassword))
```

And my CustomButtonStyle looks like this:

```
@State var disabled = false
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(15)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(disabled ? .black : .gray)
            .cornerRadius(40)
            .disabled(disabled) // this has no effect when inside a NavigationLink
    }
```

The UI updates correctly as the user types in the password.
You can see that I disable the button inside the ButtonStyle, but this doesn't prevent the user from still tapping the NavigationLink to go to `NextScreen()`.
To fix this I end up doing this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: SignupStepBirthdayView()) {
    Text("Next")
}
.buttonStyle(BobbleUpButtonStyle(disabled: !isValidPassword))
.disabled(!isValidPassword)
```

Which seems inefficient as I'm passing a disabled state to the button style to update the UI, and then having to disable the actual `NavigationLink`.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: ButtonStyle is about visual presentation of button (link in this case), not about behavior. By custom style you disabled Text label inside NavigationLink, but not the link itself - it should be disabled outside, as you already did.

Answer (score 1):

I will show you simple way, no needed to using @Bingding or @State

1. First, create your button style:

   ```
   struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

       public func makeBody(configuration: ButtonStyle.Configuration) -> some View {
           MyButton(configuration: configuration) 
       }

       struct MyButton: View {

           let configuration: ButtonStyle.Configuration

           @Environment(\.isEnabled) private var isEnabled: Bool

           var body: some View {
               configuration.label
                   .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                   .padding(15)
                   .foregroundColor(.white)
                   .background(isEnabled ? Color.blue : Color.gray)
                   .cornerRadius(40)
                   .disabled(!isEnabled)
           }    
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then, disable it as any SwiftUI component:

   ```
   struct ContentView: View {

       @State var text: String = ""

       var body: some View {
           NavigationView {
               VStack {
                   TextField("Enter your text", text: $text)
                   NavigationLink(destination: NextScreen()) {
                      Text("Next")
                   }
                   .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
                   .disabled(text.isEmpty)
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Binding instead of State in CustomButtonStyle

```
@Binding var disabled : Bool
```

And this changes in your ContentView

```
@State var isValidPassword: Bool = true
```

also:

```
.buttonStyle(BobbleUpButtonStyle(disabled: $isValidPassword))
```